# How to remove the last marker added via slider update?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking to remove the last marker from a plot to show the current data point selection.
Below is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
f0 = 0
val = 0

# Sample Data
pos_x = [0.0, 1.0, 2.5, 4.0, 8.8]
pos_y = [1.3, 2.0, 6.5, 5.0, 7.0]

# Plot all data
ax.plot(pos_x, pos_y, color="blue", marker=r'$\diamond$', linestyle='-', label="Robo")

axfreq = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor="blue")

# Create slider that will move current selection
sfreq = Slider(axfreq, 'Freq', valmin=0.0, valmax=4.0, valinit=f0, valstep=1, dragging=True)

# Adds marker at first x,y
ax.scatter(pos_x[int(val)], pos_y[int(val)], color="red", marker=r'$\spadesuit$', s=100)

# Function to update location and remove last marker
def update(val):
    freq = sfreq.val
    ax.scatter(pos_x[int(val)], pos_y[int(val)], color="red", marker=r'$\spadesuit$', s=100)
    # remove last marker
    print(pos_x[int(val)], pos_y[int(val)])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()


sfreq.on_changed(update)

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

I am currently using Python 3.9

I have been trying to find someway to revert to the base plot and then re-add the marker to the new location.

Answer (score 0):

In your `update(val)` function you don't want to create a new scatter plot, you want to update the plot that you already have created. So save the reference to the plot when you create it, name it `my_scatter_point` for example:

```
# Adds marker at first x,y
my_scatter_point = ax.scatter(
    pos_x[int(val)], pos_y[int(val)],
    color="red", marker=r'$\spadesuit$', s=100)
```

Now, in your update function you can use `my_scatter_point.set_offsets(...)` to update the values. You don't have to set the color and the marker again.

```
def update(val):
    freq = sfreq.val
    my_scatter_point.set_offsets((pos_x[int(val)], pos_y[int(val)]))
    # remove last marker
    print(pos_x[int(val)], pos_y[int(val)])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```

The plot will now update the figure when you change the slider.